# JSoup Post Request encoding

Tags: java, jsoup

I started using JSoup to handle my HTTP-requests, now I've got a question I can't seem to find the answer to.

This is my Code used for the connection, which works fine:

```
Jsoup.connect(uploadsite)
.cookies(cookies)urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
            .data("Eintrag[]" , panel.teingangsdatum.getText(), "Ticket[]", panel.tticketnr.getText(),
            "DatumA[]", datumteile[2], "DatumB[]", datumteile[1], "DatumC[]", datumteile[0],
            "UhrzeitA[]", panel.tanfangsstunde.getText(), "UhrzeitB[]", panel.tanfangsminute.getText(),
            "UhrzeitC[]", panel.tendstunde.getText(), "UhrzeitD[]", panel.tendminute.getText(),
            "KundeA[]", kdname, "KundeB[]", panel.tkdnr.getText(), "HVT[]", 
            panel.thvt.getText(),
            "Techniker[]", "0", "Art[]", ticketart)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

My problem is that in order to send the german umaults("äÄöÖüÜ"), I'll need to send the content with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as Content-Type.

Where can I see what encoding is used by jsoup and how do I change the encoding, or is it sufficient to just add `.header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer myself, by looking at the source-code of `JSoup`(which I just became aware that it was public).

In short: Yes, Jsoup encodes the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

`JSoup` uses an internal helper-class called `HttpConnection` in which

```
private static final String FORM_URL_ENCODED = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

is defined. This is used in an internal method called `String setOutputContentType(final Connection.Request req)` which is called by the `execute()` method.

While it does encode the data in the body, it does not set the content-type, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You can add additional header fields by appending

```
.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
```

to your request.

The data needs to be encoded using [`URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Full example:

```
try {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080")
            .method(Method.POST).data("fname", "ÄÖÜ-foobar").data("lname", "äöü1234")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .postDataCharset("UTF-8")
            .execute();
    System.out.println(response.statusCode() + "\n" + response.parse().text());

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output from server (using Jetty and retrieving request parameters with Request [getParameter(String name)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-), which already decodes the parameter):

```
200
Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
ÄÖÜ-foobar äöü1234
```

Reading the raw data returns

```
fname=%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C-foobar&lname=%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC1234
```

So as Meik Vtune pointed out correctly in the comments, jsoup indeed encodes the parameters.

Comment: The question is wether or not Jsoup uses said header to encode the data or if it uses something different. This does not answer the question fully.

Comment: @MeikVtune: JSoup cannot "use a header". A header is for the recipient server so it knows what to expect when processing the response body. JSoup cannot do any encoding - it will pass whatever text you gave it.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Encoding and decoding has to be done on both sides as far as I know, meaning that just sending the header with the content-type, which I have no clue what it is with JSoup, can't be the answer. If JSoup encodes the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as a standard then it's work, which is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Why guess, when you can simply set that header as suggested in this answer?

Comment: MeikVtunes question was, if jsoup handles the encoding and my first answer didn't cover that. As Andrei pointed out: jsoup/setting a header field informs the receiver about the content, so jsoup doesn't encode or validates the encoding of request parameters. I updated the answer to demonstrate the encoding.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I posted another answer in which I explain what I found in the `JSoup` source.

Comment: @F.Klein If you check my answer, you'll see that `JSoup` does indeed encode all data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @MeikVtune nice find, I was misled by the output from my server, because the parameters were already decoded, so manually encoding seemed to be the right approach. Verified now with reading the raw request data in the server, that the jsoup request is received encoded.